Difficulties Encrypting and Decrypting Files from AWS S3 using AWS KMS
[ Explanation ]
I am working on a problem that is proving to be pretty cumbersome, I feel as though I'm getting close to a solution but there's still difficulties I'm encountering.
I currently have a function configured just to test my functionality regarding the encryptFile, encryptChunk, decryptFile, decryptChunk.
I am trying to run through the functions and test to see if the decryptedFile matches the "file" from the S3 download.
[ Problem ]
The problem I seem to been encountering is that whenever I get to the Buffer.compare for fileDecryption and file they never match, always resulting in false.
I've also noticed that the decryptedFile is always MUCH smaller than the actual "file".
I've also gone as far as to log out the typeof fileDecryption and see that it's returning as type "object" which is strange...unexpected.
The encryptChunk and decryptChunk functions are a shared function that are already running effectively when encrypting and decrypting plain data or text and not files.
Hoping there might be something(s) small I am missing that may be contributing to the mismatch and result of the "file" not appropriately matching the "fileDecryption"
[ Question ]
Am I missing some step(s) here?
Is there a part of the functions that don't seem to be configured correctly?
Does it seem like these functions could handle (any) file type downloaded from S3?
i.e. { .zip, .docx, .doc, .pdf, .txt } - etc
THANK YOU, to any and all that have taken the time to read, understand and respond to my despair!
You are GREATLY Appreciated!!
[ LATEST LOGS (ATTMEPT) BELOW ]
    LOG: Type Of fileDec: object
    LOG: Actual File Length:1981185
    LOG: Decrypted File Length:4096
    LOG: Actual File Sample: 504b03041400060008000000210041f0a5c998010000c2070000130008025b436f6e74656e745f54797065735d2e786d6c20a2040228a0000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    LOG: Decrypted File Sample: 504b03041400060008000000210041f0a5c998010000c2070000130008025b436f6e74656e745f54797065735d2e786d6c20a2040228a0000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
    LOG: Actual file vs Decrypted
    LOG: false

CODE BELOW
[ TEST Functions to Call Encrypt/Decrypt ]

    async function downloadFromS3(filepath) {
      const bucket = env.BUCKET || null;
      const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: filepath.slice(1, filepath.length),
      };
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks = [];
        let stream;
        if (!bucket) {
          stream = new Readable();
          stream.push('This happens in lower ENVS');
          stream.push(null);
        } else {
          stream = awsS3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
        }
        stream.on('data', (chunk) => {
          chunks.push(chunk);
        });
        stream.on('end', () => {
          resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks));
        });
        stream.on('error', (err) => {
          reject(err);
        });
      });
    };

    async function encryptFilesTest(req) {
      try {
        console.log('START Encrypting Files');
        const keyId = env.SOME_KEY;
        const filesQry = () => `
          SELECT
            *
          FROM
            db.table
        `;
        const dbFiles = await db.execute(filesQry(), {});

        for await (let fileRecord of dbFiles) {
          if (fileRecord && fileRecord.path) {
            const file = await downloadFromS3(fileRecord.path);

            // Considered using const newReadbleStream = Readable.from([actualFile])
            // Unsure if this change is necessary based on downloadFromS3 return
            const newReadableStream = Readable.from([Buffer.from(file)]);

            console.log('ENCRYPTION / DECRYPTION RESULTS');
            const fileEncryption = await encryptFile(
              keyId,
              newReadableStream
            );

            const fileEncStream = Readable.from([fileEncryption]);
            const fileDecryption = await decryptFile(
              keyId,
              fileEncStream
            );

            console.log('Actual File Length:', file.length);
            console.log('Decrypted File Length:', fileDecryption.length);
            console.log('[Actual file] vs [Decrypted]');
            console.log(Buffer.compare(fileDecryption, file) === 0);
          }
        }
        return { success: true };
      } catch (err) {
        console.log('SOME ERROR HERE');
      }
    }



[ Encrypt File, and Encrypt Chunk Functions ]

    export const encryptChunk = (
      keyId,
      plainChunk,
      chunkId
    ) => (
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          kms.encrypt({
            Plaintext: plainChunk,
            KeyId: keyId,
          }, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(Buffer.from(result.CiphertextBlob).toString('hex'));
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('THIS IS A CATCH ERROR[ENC CHNK]:', error);
          reject(new Error(error.message));
        }
      })
    );

    export const encryptFile = async (keyId, fileReadStream) => {
      if (!fileReadStream) throw new Error('Value to encrypt blank');
      if (!keyId || !keyId.length) {
        return fileReadStream;
      }
      let encryptBuffer = '';
      const encryptedChunks = [];
      for await (const chunk of fileReadStream) {
        try {
          const chunkBuffer = Buffer.isBuffer(chunk) ? chunk : Buffer.from(chunk);
          encryptBuffer += chunkBuffer.toString('hex');

          while (encryptBuffer.length >= maxChunkSize * 2) {
            const encryptedChunk = encryptBuffer.slice(0, maxChunkSize * 2);
            encryptBuffer = encryptBuffer.slice(maxChunkSize * 2);

            const encryptedData = await encryptChunk(keyId, Buffer.from(encryptedChunk, 'hex'), 'enc0-chnk-fil');
            encryptedChunks.push(encryptedData);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('THIS IS THE CATCH ERROR (ENCFILE):', error);
          throw error;
        }
      }
      if (encryptBuffer.length > 0) {
        const encryptedData = await encryptChunk(keyId, Buffer.from(encryptBuffer, 'hex'), 'enc1-chnk-fil');
        encryptedChunks.push(encryptedData);
      }
      const encryptedData = encryptedChunks.join(';');
      return Buffer.from(encryptedData, 'hex');
    };


[ Decrypt File, and Decrypt Chunk Functions ]

    export const decryptChunk = (keyId, encrypted) => (
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        try {
          const cipherBlob = Buffer.from(encrypted, 'hex');
          if (!cipherBlob || !cipherBlob.length) {
            console.error('THERE WAS AN ERROR DECRYPTING CHUNK');
            return resolve(encrypted);
          }

          kms.decrypt({
            CiphertextBlob: cipherBlob,
            KeyId: keyId,
          }, (error, result) => {
            if (error) {
              return reject(error);
            }
            return resolve(Buffer.from(result.Plaintext));
          });
        } catch (error) {
          console.error('THIS IS THE CATCH ERROR: ', error);
          reject(new Error(error.message));
        }
      })
    );


    export const decryptFile = async (keyId, encryptedStream) => {
      if (!encryptedStream) throw new Error('Encrypted value blank');
      if (!keyId || !keyId.length) {
        return encryptedStream;
      }
      const decryptedChunks = [];
      let buffer = '';
      for await (const encryptedChunk of encryptedStream) {
        buffer += encryptedChunk.toString('hex');
        while (buffer.includes(';')) {
          const delimiterIndex = buffer.indexOf(';');
          const encryptedChunk = buffer.slice(0, delimiterIndex);
          buffer = buffer.slice(delimiterIndex + 1);

          const encChunkBuffer = Buffer.from(encryptedChunk, 'hex');
          decryptedChunks.push(
            await decryptChunk(keyId, encChunkBuffer)
          );
        }
      }
      if (buffer.length > 0) {
        const encChunkBuffer = Buffer.from(buffer, 'hex');
        decryptedChunks.push(
          await decryptChunk(keyId, encChunkBuffer)
        );
      }
      return Buffer.concat(decryptedChunks);
    };



Thank you I believe I understand your point, I am going to attempt a single file as a .txt and examine the sizes with this method, instead of pulling any random file.
If I can isolate that the encryption and decryption is working for a .txt I could progress through other file types and possibly determine the root cause for the sizing differences, If I can't clear the .txt I know something within my methods is likely incorrect.

Unfortunately the goal is taking files that are uploaded to S3 and enforcing the contents to be encrypted, such as if an individual maliciously tried to or had access to S3 and downloaded the file directly would not be able to see any of the contents without having had the app, download, decrypt and present the file to them.
The purpose being a secondary form of encryption on the file contents themselves to ensure appropriate access only to the file contents.
Going to check on that file and attempt it myself on Monday
